# how to hide website technologies information from nginx

Tags: nginx, browser

i want to know how can hide the website technology information from wappalyzer or there tools.

I have done some google search what i got is to make changes in nginx.conf file

```
server_tokens off;
```

and

```
more_clear_headers Server;
```

and

```
more_set_headers 'Server: some-string-here';
```

i tried to all the above things but it is not working. i am still able to get the site information

Please let me know how can i hide it.

i am using Ubuntu:16.04 and  nginx version: nginx/1.10.3.

and also what to do if it is running behind the proxy server

Thanks

Comment: You shouldn't be seeing your nginx version with `server_tokens off` directive. Did you restart nginx? This will only hide the server version number, but not the server signature (name). If you want to hide the server name, compile Nginx from sources and include the `--build=name` option to set a nginx build name.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I want to hide very information like, wordpress, php version, servername, some other information like analytics, libraries etc.